# Open LDAP Auditing not showing timestamp when deleting members

Tags: openldap

We are preparing an audit script for LDAP and we have openldap.

The auditlog has timestamp when adding a new member or modifying a member.

The audit.ldif is as follows:

```
# add 144294514 dc=com,cn=admin IP=...
dn:..
modifyTimestamp: 20150922180548Z
# end add 1442945148

# modify 1442945124 dc=com,cn=admin IP=...
...
-
replace: modifyTimestamp
modifyTimestamp: 20150922180524Z
-
# end modify 1442945124

# delete 1442945148 dc=com,cn=admin IP=...
dn: ...
changetype: delete
# end delete 1442945148
```

Here we have timestamp for both add and modify. However, there is no timestamp for delete.

I couldn't find any useful information on how to enable timestamp for LDAP Auditing delete operation.

Is there a way to log the delete timestamp in the audit log?

The audit report is expected to show user actions on a daily basis and timestamp is mandatory.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Comment: So, we don't have a solution in openLDAP?

Comment: There can't be timestamps in the delete LDIF, because there is no entry to put the timestamp into. So it's put there in the surrounding comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are timestamps in your log.

the "modifyTimestamp:" is NOT what you should searching for, this is just the attribute was is set in ldap, at the entry.

your auditlog uses UNIX timestamps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

look at the

```
# delete TIMESTAMP dc=com,cn=admin IP=...
..
# end delete TIMESTAMP
```

that translates to (for my timezone)

```
Di 22. Sep 20:05:48 CEST 2015
```

on linux cmd use

```
date --date='@TIMESTAMP'
```

to translate that timestamps, or use an online converter

Comment: Thank you and I never thought like that.